# how to include a standalone file in the built bookdown website?

Tags: r, r-markdown, gitbook, bookdown

i am trying to include a custom `404.html` file in the bookdown `/docs/` output folder of my `:gitbook:` output.  if i just copy the file into the `/docs/` then it ends up getting deleted any time i run `clean_site()` so i'm not sure if i'm supposed to be placing the file elsewhere?

[this `rmarkdown` page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html#site_configuration) makes it look like i should just be able to include the file in the project's home directory `/` but that doesn't appear to work with `render_site()`.

[this bookdown.org page](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html) explains how to add a snippet of html code to the html pages rendered, but not a standalone file.

sorry if i'm missing this somewhere obvious.  thanks!

Comment: How about `file.copy('404.html', 'docs/404.html', overwrite = TRUE)` in a certain R code chunk of any Rmd file?

Comment: great.  glad i didn't miss this while reading the docs.  i'll use your suggestion.  thank you for the amazing software