# Embed data files in bookdown

Tags: r, embed, bookdown

I am wanting to embed some data files into my bookdown. Is there a way to do so?

I know that [this method](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/embed-file.html) can embed arbitrary files in the HTML output.

But I wonder how can I do this systematically across other [outputs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/output-formats.html), such as e-books?

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: I'm not aware of a generic method of embedding files in any document formats.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thank you very much for your comment. I have a rather naive question, does [this method](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/embed-file.html) solves the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632715/how-to-include-a-standalone-file-in-the-built-bookdown-website) ? When I use the function embed, I cannot see the data included in the output file

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any connection between the method (`embed_file()`) and the problem you mentioned (copy `404.html`). If you have a new question, please ask and clarify in a new post. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I solved the problem now. I will ask another question if needed.

Comment: If you found a solution, you are welcome to answer your own question below (I'd also love to know how). Thanks!